# Randomly distributing numbers on a line, controlling density

Tags: statistics

This problem is for me quite difficult to describe - and hence I can't easily google it, so forgive me for not being able to google.

Now it is easy to create a random distribution, say we have a function $P(n)$ which gives a uniform random distribution in the range $[0, n)$. Now it is quite easy using the probability density function to convert this to any shape one wishes to get.

However this isn't quite what I like. I wish to get $m$ numbers that are distributed evenly on an interval. However normally this also means the density of the numbers is "evenly distributed". I however wish to make a function which almost evenly distributed the numbers, and have control over the density function (ie density of the numbers should be gaussian shaped).

(How) can I do this? What is the way to do this? - In the end I'd like to change the random distribution to a random location vector (say place the points in a 2d rectangle, or 3d cube)